# Error: TemplateDoesNotExist at / blog/home.html "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500

Tags: python, django

I'm going through a Youtube tutorial of someone showing how to create an online blog (to be more specific, his names Corey Schafer, if that helps in any way).

I've written everything just as he has done, but I'm still getting a

```
TemplateDoesNotExist / blog/home.html
```

every time I run my terminal and pull up the link. I was looking through the comments and someone said:

"Hey, great Tutorial but you didn't tell to add directory i.e. blog/template into the template section of settings.py file, without this, the browser is showing an error that your template doesn't exist."
If he's right, I'm not sure where I would put that code specifically in the Templates sections under setting.py (I've added this code below). If he's not right, does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Please let me know if you need to see more code. I tried to put everything in here that's relevant.

My Views.py File:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html')


def about(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Blog About</h1')
```

I have a fold named templates, then in that folder is another fold named blog with two files in that: about.html and home.html with the following code in each file:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>About</h1>
</body>
</html>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Blog home!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

then in another file named apps.py, I have this code:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class BlogConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'blog'
```

Which I used to install an app in my settings.py file (Templates is at the bottom):

```
'blog.apps.BlogConfig',

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',    <------- Here
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

 MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_second_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND':   'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
             'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Hello, can you show a structure of your project directory?

Comment: @sslloo I'm not sure how I would do that :/